# Python Ttk Entry widget never displaying textvariable value

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Trying to use `textvariable` to set the text of a python tkinter/ttk entry widget. The value of the `StringVar` is correctly set, but the text still fails to appear in the entry widget.

In this question, [Cannot make default value display for for ttk entry widget using the textvariable parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519740/cannot-make-default-value-display-for-for-ttk-entry-widget-using-the-textvariabl), the solution was to make the textvariable a class variable using self, however in my code the issue still persists. I have presented an example of my code (this class is being executed by another):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class example: 

    def __init__(self): 
        pass
        
    def __call__(self):
        self.file1 = StringVar(value = "default value")
        self.file2 = StringVar(value = "default value")

        def select_file_1():
             self.file1.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File", filetype = (("txt", "*.txt"), ("All Files","*.*"))))
        def select_file_2():
            self.file2.set(filedialog.askopenfilename())
        
        root = Tk()
        root.title("example program")

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        style = ttk.Style(root)
        style.configure("TLabel", font = ("TkDefaultFont", 12))

        ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Select file 1: ", command=select_file_1).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W))
        self.file1Entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable=self.file1).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(E))
        ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Select file 2: ", command=select_file_2).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W))
        self.file2Entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 60, textvariable=self.file2).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(E))

        for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): 
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

        root.mainloop()
```

Update: issue still persists when line 15 and 17 are fixed to
`self.file1.set(filedialog.askopenfilename())`

Comment: The code you posted won't run for me. Nothing instantiates `example`, and if I instantiate it and then call it I get errors. Please make sure your example is complete. That being said, `self.file1` starts out as a `StringVar` but then you overwrite it with the result `askopenfilename`.

Comment: Right.  You probably want `self.file1.set(filedialog.asko[enfilename(...))` and `self.file2.set(filedialog.askopenfilename())`.

Comment: @BryanOakley `self.file1` still is not displayed before or after askopenfilename is called, even when changing line 15 to `self.focusFile.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File", filetype = (("txt", "*.txt"), ("All Files","*.*"))))`

Comment: @DarianSiembab: what is `self.focusFile`? Your code doesn't have that anywhere.

Comment: Most probably there are more than one instance of `Tk()` because you can create `self.file1` and `self.file2` (instances of `StringVar()`) before the line `root = Tk()`.

Answer (score 2):

Bryan is correct. You're overwriting `self.file1` and `self.file2` with a different object instead of setting their values.

```
def __call__(self):
    self.file1 = StringVar(value = "default value")
    self.file2 = StringVar(value = "default value")

    def select_file_1():
        file1_selection = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir="/",
            title="Select a File",
            filetype=(("txt", "*.txt"), ("All Files","*.*"))
        )
        # store the value of from the dialog in the file1 variable via 'set()'
        self.file1.set(file1_selection)
  
  
    def select_file_2():
        file2_selection = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        # store the value of from the dialog in the file2 variable via 'set()'
        self.file2.set(file2_selection)
```